# current_user devise on invalid form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

this is a simple problem. but i wonder if there any better solutions

i'm using current_user from Devise to display user's username on navbar.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li class="someclass"> hi,<%= current_user.username  %> 
    ...
```

I'm allowing user to edit their username through edit account setting page, i'm also using validation to prevent user from choosing reserved username (like admin, support etc) so if a user tries to edit his username to invalid username let's say by input 'admin', the form will return validation error message. This works well.

however, i noticed that if a user tries to change his username to 'admin', while the form displaying the validation error message, the greeting will says " hi,admin". I know that username are not saved to the database  because of the validation. If i navigate away form the page the greeting will back normal "Hi, JhonDoe1"

here is my controller method to update this

```
class ProfilesController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def update_settings
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params_settings)
    flash[:notice] = 'Your account was successfully updated!'
    redirect_to settings_path
  else
    render "settings"
  end
end

def user_params_settings
  params.required(:user).permit(:username, :email, :current_password)
end
```

i can use the following code to fix this, so when user tries to submit invalid username the greeting will keep say ex:"Hi, JhonDoe1"

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <li class="someclass"> hi,<%= User.find(current_user.id).username  %> 
    ...
```

But this code will generate 1 extra query (so there will be 2 similar user queries)

```
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

and since this code are called in almost every page on the app,  so this is not effective. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does your whole form look like? Quite confused as to why users are able to edit their username if you dont want them to? Probably could consider disabling that field on submission? And if need be just put a hidden field as your intended value instead?

Comment: @angkiki i edited the question. hope i explained this problem well.

Comment: Okay heres a two things. 1) I don't think you should be passing `User.find(current_user.id).username` in your views. You ideally should have a instance variable from your controller to work with in your view instead. 2) If the data from the form is not hitting your database, there shouldn't be a reason the user's username is changing. So you may wanna show your logs as to why when someone passes `admin` the change seems to be reflected.